# Alfresco Create Content From Dashlet

Tags: java, javascript, yui, alfresco, alfresco-share

How can i put link of creating content from dashlet?
This link should show popup of creating selected type of content...

I have seen site blog dashlet from share-extras...

I tried with this but didn't

```
<@markup id="html">
  <@uniqueIdDiv>
    <div class="create-content-mgr">
     <div class="heading">${msg("create-content-mgr.heading")}</div>
    </div>
   </@>
</@>
```

Can you give me some concrete example

Answer (score -1):

You should call previously written webscript for creating a node of some type from your dashlet. If this way fits to you I can show you simple example. BTW, I am not confident about "link of creating content", as usual buttons being used for doing some action.